# Rename and retain the source file by using C++

Tags: c++

I would like to rename and retain the source file by using C++. I use this for renaming the file.

For eg:

rename(source_file.txt, destination_file.txt);

In this, I would like to retain the source_file.txt. By default, this function deletes the source_file and saves it as destination_file.

Comment: So you don't want to rename it, just copy it? Open source file, create new file(that will be a copy), then simply read line by line or whatever and copy original file to new file.

Comment: It doesn't delete the file. It renames the file. Same file, new name. That is the purpose of that function.
If you want to keep the source, you must copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest, most reliable and most portable method is to use [`boost::filesystem::copy_file()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_file):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

copy_file("source_file.txt", "destination_file.txt", copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
```